# Таймер js внутри цикла

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, settimeout, таймер

Есть функция, которая отрисовывает график по полученному массиву с помощью AJAX.

```
// ********************************** startUpdate ******************************** //
    function startUpdate() {

        fetchData();
        data = [];
        alreadyFetched = {};

        $('#average').hide();
        var currentTemperatureHolder = $('.currentTemperatureHolder');

        function fetchData() {

            function beforeSendFunc() {
                tempSpan.hide();
                lastUpdateTimeHolder.hide();
                preloaderHolder.show();
            }

            function completeFunc(answer_code) {
                if(answer_code.responseText === 'DATA IS EMPTY') {
                    alert('Данные отсутствуют');
                    return;
                }
            }

            function showData() {
                tempSpan.show();
                lastUpdateTimeHolder.show();
                preloaderHolder.hide();
                return true;
            }

            function onDataReceived(series) {

                $('.tempSpan').text(series[+series.length - 1][1]);
                var lastUpdateTime = new Date(+series[+series.length - 1][0]  - 10800000);
                var hours = lastUpdateTime.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getHours() : lastUpdateTime.getHours();
                var minutes = lastUpdateTime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getMinutes() : lastUpdateTime.getMinutes();
                var seconds = lastUpdateTime.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getSeconds() : lastUpdateTime.getSeconds();
                var lastUpdateTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                $('.lastUpdateTime').text(lastUpdateTime);

                showData();

                data = [ series ];
                $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: './getTemperature.php',
                beforeSend: beforeSendFunc,
                complete: completeFunc,
                success: onDataReceived
            });
        }
        setInterval(fetchData, 5000);
    }
```

Хочу в этой функции выводит время до обновления, то есть выводит в таймер 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 - пошел аякс запрос, приехал, вывел данные, и пошел 5, 4, 3...

Пробовал по-разному, но количество вызовов функции таймера растет в геометрической прогрессии. Из примера удалил функцию timer дабы не пугать общественность.

Буду благодарен корректному решению и даже подсказке.

Comment: Если кому интересно, то это график, который показывает кривую изменений температуры в серверной комнате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте вместе порассуждаем) 
Первое что пришло в голову, это повесить параллельно с fetchData еще один таймер, но ведь нету никакой гарантии что ответ будет прислан моментально из за этого и следует что корректный таймер мы сделать не можем. НО в вашем условии есть замечательная ремарка и в ajax запросе есть прелоадер (beforeSendFunc()).
В итоге, мы делаем следующее, запускаем параллельно с основным таймером другой, который будет запускаться 1 раз в 1000 мс и который будет выполнять дикримент счетчика 5..4..3..2.. когда счетчик будет равен 0 можно ждать ответ от функции beforeSendFunc() можно с её помощью более жестко словить начало запроса, а в onDataReceived() мы снова даем счетчику значение 5

Comment: Примерно так и решил задачу, но действительно задача не из легких, 2 дня ушло на решение, не мог уснуть - ворочился :)

Comment: @Anton, я рад что вы решили задачу) был рад помочь

Answer (score 0):

```
        // ********************************** startUpdate ******************************** //
    function startUpdate() {
        timeToRefresh.show();
        data = [];
        alreadyFetched = {};

        $('#average').hide();
        var currentTemperatureHolder = $('.currentTemperatureHolder');

        function fetchData() {

            function beforeSendFunc() {
                $('#timeToRefresh').hide();
                tempSpan.hide();
                lastUpdateTimeHolder.hide();
                preloaderHolder.show();
            }

            function showData() {
                $('#timeToRefresh').show();
                tempSpan.show();
                lastUpdateTimeHolder.show();
                preloaderHolder.hide();
            }

            function onDataReceived(series) {

                $('.tempSpan').text(series[+series.length - 1][1].toFixed(1));
                $('.tempSpan').append('&#176;C');
                var lastUpdateTime = new Date(+series[+series.length - 1][0]  - 10800000);
                var hours = lastUpdateTime.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getHours() : lastUpdateTime.getHours();
                var minutes = lastUpdateTime.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getMinutes() : lastUpdateTime.getMinutes();
                var seconds = lastUpdateTime.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + lastUpdateTime.getSeconds() : lastUpdateTime.getSeconds();
                var lastUpdateTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                $('.lastUpdateTime').text(lastUpdateTime);

                showData();

                data = [ series ];
                $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: './getTemperature.php',
                type: "post",
                beforeSend: beforeSendFunc,
                success: onDataReceived
            });
        }

        function startTimer() {
            if(icycle === 0) {
                icycle  = 61;
                fetchData();
            }
            var my_timer = $('#timeToRefresh');
            var time = my_timer.innerHTML;

            icycle --;
            icycle = icycle < 10 ? '0' + icycle : icycle;
            my_timer.text(icycle);
            icycle =+ icycle;
        }           
        setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    }
```